# How to change plot size in ggforest (or coxph regression plot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Is there a functionality to increase plot size? I have +20 features and the plot is cluttered even after reducing font-size.

```
output$coxplot <- renderPlot({ 
   fit.coxph<- coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ feature1 + feature2 +...+featureN, data=data)
    print(ggforest(fit.coxph, data = dat, fontsize = 0.3,noDigits = 3) )
  })
```

Trying to render in shiny and adjust the plot height and width or the size but no parameters in ggforest function called "size" but there is "fontsize".

Comment: What do you mean by plot size? Are you saving the plot as an image, or just viewing it in your R session? When saving as an image you can pick the size of the image.

Comment: I am just trying to view it using print. The graph generated per this post - there seems to be no way to increase the size lets say if you are plotting 30 covariates : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627999/how-to-add-arrows-to-forest-plot-in-survminer-ggforest/55630623#55630623

Comment: If you're using RStudio, you can make a plot larger by clicking the "zoom" button in the plotting pane (and resize the window if you need it even bigger after that). In R you "print" plots to a device, and there are different ways of controlling the size of each device, so it's a bit hard to know what to do here without knowing how you're viewing the plot.

Comment: Thank you - I just updated my post. I am actually trying to render it in shiny. So I need to adjust the plot's width and height in shiny. Even without shiny rendering - there is no way to give a size parameter in ggforest function.

Answer (score 2):

@marius: thank you. Your questions hinted me towards answering my own question. in the shiny app, setting size in ui worked instead of in ggforest as a parameter. `plotOutput(outputId = "coxplot", height = 750)`

Would like to know how to set size parameter in **ggforest** if I weren't using shiny.